# What types of methods can we call from a .NET assembly in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-clr

After we have registered a DLL in SQL Server (in Programmability -> Assemblies), can we call any type of method from that .NET assembly in SQL Server? Or just static ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQLCLR is a very limited CLR host. Yes, you can only call static methods due to the App Domain being shared across all sessions (i.e. @@SPID), and hence any "shared" instances or variables would be very much not "thread safe". App Domains are created on a per-Database, per-"owner" (i.e. whatever User is listed in the `AUTHORIZATION` clause of `CREATE ASSEMBLY`, or `dbo` as the default if that clause is omitted), so there is a minimal amount of separation, but for any given method that is exposed via a `CREATE {object} AS EXTERNAL NAME` statement, any User in any Session executing that SQLCLR Stored Procedure, Function, Trigger, or User-Defined Type will be hitting the exact same App Domain. This is why you are also not allowed to store values in static class variables (unless they are marked as `readonly`) as they are shared across Sessions and one Session can overwrite the value that another Session just stored and hence you would get odd / erratic / unpredictable behavior.

Regarding SQLCLR being a restricted environment:

- Please see the following MSDN page for a list of what is *not* allowed in SQLCLR: [CLR Integration Programming Model Restrictions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403273.aspx).
- Please see the following MSDN page for a list of what few .NET Framework libraries *are* included in SQLCLR: [Supported .NET Framework Libraries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403279.aspx).
- For more information on working with SQLCLR in general, please see the series I am writing on this topic on SQL Server Central (free registration is required to read their content, but it's worth it): [Stairway to SQLCLR](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/105855/).